qgis2threejs labels not showing
A few years ago I created this 3D map in qgis2threejs:

but now when I try to render it the labels will not appear, nor will they labels appear for any new project that I create in qgis2threejs.
Now the map just looks like this:


I opened an issue to fix this bug.
https://github.com/minorua/Qgis2threejs/issues/355
